# WebSocket server from scratch showing opcode -1

Tags: perl, websocket

I am trying to create a simple WebSocket server in perl from scratch, when I tried it in Google Chrome it gave me *opcode -1*, How can I fix it?

#### websocket.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use Digest::SHA1 "sha1_base64";
 
$| = 1;

my $magic_string = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";


# Create a server
my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new( LocalHost => 'localhost',
                                    LocalPort => 7777,
                                    Proto     => 'tcp',
                                    Listen    => 5,
                                    Reuse     => 1
) || die "$!";

print "Server is running on port 7777\n";

  
while (1) {
    my $client = $socket->accept();
    my $key = "";

    # Get the Request
    my $data = "";
    while (my $line = <$client>) {
            $data .= $line;
    }
      
    # Get the Sec-WebSocket-Key value
      foreach my $line ( split /\n/ => $data ) {
          if ( $line =~ /^Sec-WebSocket-Key: (\S+)/ ) {
                  $key = $1;
            }
      }
      print "Sec-WebSocket-Key: $key\n";
    
      # Create the Sec-WebSocket-Accept header value
      my $accept = sha1_base64($key);
      $accept .= "="x(4-(length($accept)%4));
      print "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $accept\n";
      
      # Response
      print $client "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
      print $client "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
      print $client "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
      print $client "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $accept\r\n\r\n";
      
      shutdown($client, 1);
}

$socket->close();
```

I am pretty sure that the key returned to website is correct, so where is the problem? What went wrong?

#### ws.js

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7777/");

ws.onopen = function() {
    alert("connected!");
    ws.send( 'Hello server' );
};

ws.onclose = function() {
    alert( 'Connection is closed... ');
};
```

[Web Browser network traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7wtG.png)

### Edit

*Stefan Becker*: Yea, I know, but in this case I was sure that the request is under 1024 bytes, I've fixed it, thanks.

Comment: `recv` doesn't guarantee that data is read in one chunk: "`recv SOCKET,SCALAR,LENGTH,FLAGS`
            Receives a message on a socket. **Attempts to receive LENGTH
            characters of data into variable SCALAR from the specified
            SOCKET filehandle**. SCALAR will be grown or shrunk to the length
            actually read." As you are processing HTTP you must loop until you have received all data (header + content-length body) before processing the request.

Comment: Why don't you avoid all the hassle of HTTP request parsing and let [Net::Server::HTTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Server::HTTP) do all the work? You just need to write the request handler. Maybe you should look also into [Net::WebSocket](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::WebSocket)...

Comment: Stefan Becker : Cause I enjoy using sockets (Yea, I know it's not effective or fast like using a Module for that). Yes, I cloud use Net::WebSocket, but I just want to get deeper into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Opcode -1) is a generic error. In your case it is a bad `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` header. You forgot to use `$magic_string`:

```
my $accept = sha1_base64($key.$magic_string);
```

Also `while (my $line = <$client>) {` will probably run forever. You need to check for an empty line.

Comment: The `while (my $line = <$client>) {` is running fine, it's just like when you read a file, but thanks for the answer, it's worked.